# How can I use copy command in stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with this stored procedure, I get an error when I use copy command

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COPY_PROCEDURE AS

   BEGIN

    COPY FROM USER/PASS@DB1 TO USER/PASS@DB2 REPLACE TABLE1 USING  select * from TABLE2;

   END;
```

Comment: _"send error when i use copy command"_   And you want us to guess the error?  Can _you_ start diagnosing an error without knowing what the error is?  Oracle emits error codes for a reason.  If _you_ expect to diagnose a problem, _you_ have to know the full error message stack.  If you expect _someone else_ to diagnose an error, you have to give _them_ the full error message stack.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy command is niche facility supported by few oracle client tools. It is not integrated with oracle backend (RDBMS).

```
create table cloneA as select * from A@dblink
```

is much cleaner way to copy a table from one db instance to the other.